# .htacces replace all underscores with hyphens

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration

I am having a struggle trying to get my .htaccess to remove all underscores from an url. I have a lot of old aliases in my articles and they are all with underscores. I have searched for a sollution, but couldnt find any.

**example:**

http://mysite.com/nl/nieuws/artikel/Article_name_underscores/999

http://mysite.com/nl/nieuws/artikel/article_name_with_underscores/999

http://mysite.com/nl/nieuws/artikel/article_name_with_More_underscores/999

**What I am trying to get:**

http://mysite.com/nieuws/article-name-with-underscore

http://mysite.com/nieuws/article-name-with-more-underscore

http://mysite.com/nieuws/article-name-with-even-more-underscore

As you can see I need to **replace the underscore with hyphens** and get it **into lowercase**, but **the aliases are between 1 and 14 underscores**. Now I've created the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^nieuws/artikel/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)/([^_]*)$ http://mysite.com/nieuws/${lc:$1}-${lc:$2}-${lc:$3} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws/artikel/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)/([^_]*)$ http://mysite.com/nieuws/${lc:$1}-${lc:$2}-${lc:$3}-${lc:$4} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws/artikel/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)/([^_]*)$ http://mysite.com/nieuws/${lc:$1}-${lc:$2}-${lc:$3}-${lc:$4}-${lc:$5} [R=301,L]
```

With the RewriteMap on the virtualhost ofcourse

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

My question is, how do I get this dynamicly with efficient code to catch all alias between unlimited amounts of underscores?

Comment: Probably not relevant to you, but just in case - you can do redirects with Joomla! system plugins. I do not know any that does exactly what you want, but **if** you happen to have the skills to write plugins it should fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest way, but it works.  Because of the [L] in it for Last rule, it won't be a redirect loop because it exits once applied:

```
# Four underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [L,R=301]

# Three underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [L,R=301]

# Two underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)_(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [L,R=301]

# One underscore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I changed my question, to clarify my question. I got the code you send already. Thanks for your help anyway! I hope you can help me further?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this at the .htaccess level, replace your Joomla links in the database (by using the MySQL `REPLACE` command), and then create a simple PHP redirect in the `defines.php` file (you can read more about this file [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/leveraging-the-power-of-the-defines-php-file-to-monitor-post-requests-on-joomla-websites)). You will have better control on your links this way.

Essentially, you will need to have the following code in your `defines.php` file (replace `http://` below with `https://` if your site uses https):

```
<?php
    $currentURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos ($currentURL, '_') !== FALSE){
        $currentURL = str_replace('_', '-', $currrentURL);
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
        header("Location: ".$currentURL); 
        exit(); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: No, I have to do this in the .htaccess level, because otherwise my links in google won't work anymore, I think I wasn't clear enough, I am sorry! I need the google links to go to my article links but in google the links have underscores and I have - but I dont want to do this by changing my data in the database with hyphens.

Comment: Your links should work in Google. There will be a 301 redirect from the underscored to the hyphened link.